# holomorphic function power series: $f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j(z-z_0)^j$, can it be extended to $U$?

Tags: complex-analysis

It's well know that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $U\subseteq \mathscr C$, then $f(z)$ could be expanded as a power series $$f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j(z-z_0)^j$$ in $D(z_0,r)$, if $z_0 \in U$, $\bar D \subset U$.

I wonder, if such power series could be extended to the whole $U$, not only limited to $D(z_0,r)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a well-known fact that the power series will converge until a singularity of $f$ is reached.

Example: the function $f(z)=\frac1z$. For any $z_0\ne 0$ the radius of convergence of the power series
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n$$
is $|z_0|$ (distance from $z_0$ to the pole $z=0$).

Comment: is there a theorem for this?

Comment: @athos, see the proof at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions.